# CSS Animation, move element in front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 elements that overlap each other, on hover I want to animate the bottom element out to the right and then move back left but on top of the other element, on mouseleave I then want it to animate back to its default state. I've got something working only the opacity issue is making it quite buggy and not as smooth as I'd have liked...

https://codepen.io/liamgallagher/pen/vWrYOe?editors=1100

**CSS**

```
body {
  background:#cacaca;
}

.sector-card {
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  .sector-panel {
    width:50%;
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    &__information {
      background:#fff;
      z-index:1;
      position:relative;       
    }
    &__study {
      background-size:cover;
      z-index:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:15%;
      right:25%;
    }
  }
  &:hover {
    .sector-panel__study {
      animation:moveFront 2s forwards;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes moveFront {
  0%   { right:25%; }
  50% {z-index:3; right:0;}
  100% { opacity: 1; right:25%;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sector-card">
  <div class="sector-panel sector-panel__information">
    <h2>Big Data</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum oosh</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sector-panel sector-panel__study" style="background-image:url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQDvM3R_A9_W32EdH7pqK-CgCg9fSLcLoXi5EbV_D0CxtrJpXYn');">
    <h2>case study</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked your pen. I just added some more brekpoints to the animation and changed the css slightly on the hover event. I think this is what you want (link to forked pen and css below)

https://codepen.io/ecglover8/pen/qVKBxX

```
body {
  background:#cacaca;
}

.sector-card {
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  .sector-panel {
    width:50%;
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    &__information {
      background:#fff;
      z-index:1;
      position:relative;       
    }
    &__study {
      background-size:cover;
      z-index:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:15%;
      right:25%;
    }
  }
  &:hover {
    .sector-panel__study {
      animation:moveFront 2s forwards;
      z-index:3;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes moveFront {
  0%   { z-index:-1; right:25%; }
  49% {z-index:-1;right:0;}
  50% {z-index:3;right:0;}
  100% {right:25%;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ecg8, that's it works to an extent, but how do I reverse the animation on mouse leave?

Comment: I think we'd need to use onmouseout with JS in order to achieve that. Would that be okay or are you looking for a pure CSS solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't transition `z-index`. One thing you can do is transition `opacity` to make it appear smoother.

Something like:

```
@keyframes moveFront {
  0%   { right:25%; opacity: 0; }
  100% { right:0%;z-index:3; opacity: 1; }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to do the back to position part but it becomes a bit buggy because there is not opposite to :hover, so this will execute when the div is created.

Changed this to the CSS:

```
    body {
  background:#cacaca;
}
.sector-panel__study{
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation:moveBack 2s backwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}
.sector-card {
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
  .sector-panel {
    width:50%;
    display:block;
    height:300px;
    &__information {
      background:#fff;
      z-index:1;
      position:relative;       
    }
    &__study {
      background-size:cover;
      z-index:0;
      position:absolute;
      top:15%;
      right:25%;
    }
  }
  &:hover {
    .sector-panel__study {
      animation:moveFront 2s forwards;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
    }
    .sector-panel__information {
      opacity: 0.5;
      z-index: 0;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes moveFront {
  0%   { right:25%; }
  50% {z-index:3; right:0;}
  100% { opacity: 1; right:25%;}
}
@keyframes moveBack {
  0%   { z-index: 3; Right:25%; opacity:1;}
  50% {z-index:0; Right:0;}
  100% { opacity: 0.5; Right:25%;}
}
```

Can put snipped, you will have to copy this css code and test!

Comment: Yep I saw it, its the only way to achieve this without js!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the CSS only solution i got was creating another animation that will play when the mouse leave. It does, obviously, an animation when you load the page but thats because it is a CSS only solution:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YEvPNB?editors=1100

I just copied the same animation and put the values on backwards.

```
@keyframes moveBack {
    100% {
        z-index: -1;
        right: 25%;
        top: 5%;
    }
    50% {
        z-index: -1;
        right: 0;
    }
    49% {
        z-index: 3;
        right: 0;
        top: 10%;
    }
    0% {
        z-index: 3;
        right: 25%;
        top: 5%;
    }
}
```

And then i just put the naimation on your `.sector-panel__study`.

```
&__study {
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    right: 25%;
    animation: moveBack 1s forwards; // HERE
}
```

Hope this helps.